# Microsoft Excel 2010: using array functions to generate boxplot data

Tags: excel

I have a table with four columns.  Three of which are settings for the trials, and the fourth is the value generated by the experiment.  Each row represents a trial, and multiple trials for each experiment configuration was performed.  I want to build a table for each of configuration that lists the five values (min, 25th percentile, median, 75th percentile, and max) for those trials.

I've built a separate table where each unique experiment configuration is listed once.  There are extra columns with the percentile values as the column headers.  I have the following formula set up to try to calculate the five values:

```
{=PERCENTILE.INC(IF(AND($B$2:$B$35341=$G2,$C$2:$C$35341=$H2,$D$2:$D$35341=$I2),$E$2:$E$35341),J$1)}
```

This is intended to compare the row's three settings to ensure that only the trials with that row's configuration return the readings for percentile evaluation.

However, this formula only returns zeroes.

How can I generate the data I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally can't use AND's or OR's in array functions as they don't return an array, just a single TRUE or FALSE.  This multiplies the conditions together and returns blanks for the array triplets that don't resolve to TRUE.  PERCENTILE ignores the blanks and solves for the remaining elements:

```
=PERCENTILE.INC(IF(($B$2:$B$35=G2)*($C$2:$C$35=H2)*($D$2:$D$35=I2)=0,"",
($B$2:$B$35=G2)*($C$2:$C$35=H2)*($D$2:$D$35=I2)*($E$2:$E$35)),J$1)
```

Comment: This helped me get the equation I needed.  The final version was

=PERCENTILE.INC(IF(($B$2:$B$35341=$G2)*($C$2:$C$35341=$H2)*($D$2:$D$35341=$I2)<>0,$E$2:$E$35341),J$1)

Comment: I had a feeling I was doubling my logic!  Nice fix.